# Maximum overshoot and settling time for a 2nd order system

Tags: control-system

I have a second-order unity feedback control system with forward transfer function $$G(s) = \frac{10}{s(s+2)}$$

Here damping ratio, $$\zeta  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$$
and natural frequency, $$w_n = \sqrt{10}$$

First, I gave a unit step input to the system. Now I can calculate the maximum overshoot of the unit step response from $$\%M_p = e^{\frac{-\zeta\pi}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}}$$ and settling time from $$t_s = \frac{4}{w_n\zeta}$$

Now, If I give a unit ramp input to the system, Can I use the same formulas above to calculate settling time and maximum overshoot?

For reference, this is my unit ramp response in the time domain
$$y(t) = -\frac{1}{5}+t+\frac{1}{5}e^{-t}Cos(3t)-\frac{4}{15}e^{-t}Sin(3t)$$

As you can see, this is uniformly increasing. How can I find settling time from this? Can I just equate y(t) with unit ramp input and find the time at which they are equal?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the formula is obtained as the maximum value of the transient response compare to the desired one being constant. Now with a ramp, the desired value change over time. So you can not use it to give accurately the maximum overshoot. If will give you a superior bound which can not be exceeded.

Comment: Concerning the seetling time, you can not use the formula as well. By the way, in a system specification (in electronic), it is expected to give the maximum error expected associated to the settling time. For instance a settling time to 0.01% of 15ns.

Comment: I have added the ramp response of my system. Can you help me in finding the settling time?

Comment: Why did you ask [the same question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/516644/95619) again? You could have just edited it.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. I deleted the other question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, the error is the difference between desired output and the one you got:
$$e(t) = y^*(t) - y(t)$$

Then you resolve $$e(t) < ErrorMax$$.

To simplify the comparison note that
$$sin(a + b) = sin(a)cos(b) + sin(b)cos(a)$$
so
$$ a cos(\omega t) + b sin(\omega t) = M sin(\omega t + \phi)$$ where $$ M = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$ and $$\phi = atan(a/b)$$

In consequence, you get something in the form
$$M sin(\omega t + \phi) e^{-t} < ErrorMax$$

Comment: Consider that the absolute value of the error should be less than ErrorMax

Comment: So the upper bound should be taken as my overshoot right? What about settling time?

Comment: If you expect a settling time for an error less than 0.1, solve $$M|\sin(\omega t + \phi)| e^{-t} < 0.1$$. The value of t is the settling time (in this case close to 0.961). The overshoot is the maximum value of the error where $$y > y^*$$. So the overshoot can exceed the limits you desire